# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/gemfire/util/SpringExtensions - Spring Gemfire

Tags: spring, gemfire, geode

I am using Apache Geode to develop a simple CRUD application. I've used below to start the Gemfire

```
docker run -it apachegeode/geode
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/gemfire/util/SpringExtensions
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.springframework.geode.boot.autoconfigure.RegionTemplateAutoConfiguration.lambda$setAutoConfiguredRegionTemplateDependencies$3(RegionTemplateAutoConfiguration.java:215)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1620)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.springframework.geode.boot.autoconfigure.RegionTemplateAutoConfiguration.setAutoConfiguredRegionTemplateDependencies(RegionTemplateAutoConfiguration.java:215)
    at org.springframework.geode.boot.autoconfigure.RegionTemplateAutoConfiguration.lambda$regionTemplateBeanFactoryPostProcessor$0(RegionTemplateAutoConfiguration.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:325)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.example.gemfirebasic.Application.main(Application.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.gemfire.util.SpringExtensions
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>00-gemfire-basic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>00-gemfire-basic</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-geode.version>1.7.5</spring-geode.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.geode</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-geode-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.geode</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-geode-starter-session</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.geode</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-geode-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.geode</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-geode-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.geode</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-geode-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-geode.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Customer.java

```
@Region("Customers")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "create")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @NonNull
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;
}
```

CustomerRepository.java

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    Customer findByNameLike(String name);
}
```

MainApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses = Customer.class, clientRegionShortcut = ClientRegionShortcut.LOCAL)
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Customer c1 = Customer.create(1L, "John Doe");
        Customer c2 = Customer.create(2L, "Jane Doe");
        Customer c3 = Customer.create(3L, "Jack Doe");
        Customer c4 = Customer.create(4L, "Mike Doe");
        Customer c5 = Customer.create(5L, "Matt Doe");

        customerRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5));

        customerRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Upgrade to the latests Spring Boot 2.7.x version. Looking at the Geode starter pom it requires at least Spring Boot 2.7.5.

Comment: Thanks, I used 2.7.5 and issue got resolved, infact using 2.7.15 - the only thing which I need is I want to keep data persistent, every time my application exit, data gets wiped out, any quick suggestion?

Comment: That is a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the dependencies for the 1.7.5 version](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.springframework.geode/spring-geode-starter) of Spring Data for Geode it requires at least Spring Boot 2.7.5. You are using Spring Boot 2.7.1 which at the moment lead to pulling in different jars for Spring and Spring Boot I suspect leading to incompatible versions.

So to fix upgrade to the latest Spring Boot 2.7 version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the link here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Boot-for-Apache-Geode-and-VMware-Tanzu-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix which seem very useful.