# How to persist data into Gemfire region permanently?

Tags: gemfire

Taking a reference: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/gemfire/util/SpringExtensions - Spring Gemfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78020594/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-data-gemfire-util-springexte?noredirect=1#comment137545801_78020594).

I am looking to persist the data into gemfire. Currently when my application exit, data gets wiped out.

Which changes do I need to implement?

Answer (score 0):

In order to preserve your data you should define a Disk Store as described here - https://docs.vmware.com/en/Spring-Data-for-VMware-GemFire/1.0/sdgf/reference-bootstrap-annotations.html#configuring-disk-stores-23